# codeigniter limit query not working

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, pagination, continuous-integration

I want make a pagination than i find this problem. pagination limit query not working properly.

```
if($this->input->get('page'))
{
    $start = abs(($this->input->get('page', TRUE)-1)*$config['per_page']);
}else{
    $start = 0;
}

$condition = array();

if (preg_match('/WMV/', $whatFind)) {
    $condition = array('registerId' => $whatFind);
}

$results = $this->db->
    group_by('registerId')->
    //($start, $config['per_page'])->
    order_by('id', 'desc')->
    get_where('tbl_applications', $condition)->
    result();
```

Comment: where is your `limit` call ? https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=limit#limiting-or-counting-results

Comment: add limit query like this $this->db->limit('your-limit'); in your SQL query

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the limit

```
$this->db->limit(X);
```

where X is the limit rows to return

```
$results = $this->db
    ->group_by('registerId')
    ->limit($start)
    ->order_by('id', 'desc')
    ->get_where('tbl_applications', $condition)
    ->result();
```

If you want to limit with a fixed digit (10), then you should do this in your query

```
->limit(10)
```

Comment: boss i want limit 10 item.. how i can this.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you need to define limit and add in you query.

May below link will help you

> [Codeigniter Pagination From Database limit, offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579332/codeigniter-pagination-from-database-limit-offset)